# Fetch Encrypted Data ValueError: Request failed validation

Tags: validation, pyota

I am trying to fetch bundles from the Tangle based on their tail transaction hashes. I am trying to follow [step 7](https://pyota.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials.html) of the Pyota Tutorial

I successfully encrypted data and included it in a zero-value transaction as described in [step 6](https://pyota.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials.html). The transaction is visible in the Tangle Explorer and a nice green **Confirmed** tag is associated with it.

Unfortunately when I run the script and insert the Tail transaction hash of the bundle I get the following error:

```
Looking for bundle on the Tangle...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_encrypted_transaction.py", line 21, in <module>
    bundle = api.get_bundles([tail_hash])['bundles'][0]
  File "/home/userk/development/git/autodichiarazione_2.0/consistency_check/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/iota/api.py", line 721, in get_bundles
    return extended.GetBundlesCommand(self.adapter)(transaction=transaction)
  File "/home/userk/development/git/autodichiarazione_2.0/consistency_check/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/iota/commands/__init__.py", line 126, in __call__
    replacement = self._prepare_request(self.request)
  File "/home/userk/development/git/autodichiarazione_2.0/consistency_check/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/iota/commands/__init__.py", line 300, in _prepare_request
    failure_message = 'Request failed validation',
  File "/home/userk/development/git/autodichiarazione_2.0/consistency_check/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/iota/commands/__init__.py", line 335, in _apply_filter
    'filter_errors': runner.get_errors(with_context=True),
ValueError: Request failed validation ({'transaction': ['wrong_type']}) (`exc.context["filter_errors"]` contains more information).
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
Here is the complete exception info:

```
Looking for bundle on the Tangle...
{'filter_errors': {'transaction': [{'code': 'wrong_type',
                                    'context': {'code': 'wrong_type',
                                                'filter': 'Type(TryteString, '
                                                          'bytearray, bytes, '
                                                          'str, '
                                                          'allow_subclass=True)',
                                                'key': 'transaction',
                                                'replacement': None,
                                                'value': ['QEZGSZYP9FXJZJIZQJILXGMIMMFQXGFGP9NOGDJJV9PAWJRYLTACOICVKOPYUVVCTNPFDJUTQPAJMI999']},
                                    'exc_info': None,
                                    'message': 'list is not valid (allowed '
                                               'types: TryteString, bytearray, '
                                               'bytes, str).'}]}}
```

*Additional Infos*

```
pip show pyota
Name: PyOTA
Version: 2.1.0
Summary: IOTA API library for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.py
Author: Phoenix Zerin
Author-email: phx@phx.ph
License: MIT
Location: /home/userk/development/git/autodichiarazione_2.0/consistency_check/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: pysha3, requests, six, phx-filters
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for including the additional info in your question!

I was about to write the answer to update to the newest PyOTA version, but you were faster with your comment.

So yes, PyOTA 2.3.0b1 should solve the issue! :)

Comment: Glad to accept your first answer as the solution

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the IOTA StackExchange!  I'm sorry (and a tad embarrassed ) to hear that you encountered an error during the tutorials!  Hopefully we can get you back on track quickly!

The error message indicates two things:

> Request failed validation ({'transaction': ['wrong_type']})

PyOTA attempted to craft a request to fetch information about the bundle, but somewhere (internally, it seems), there was a `transaction` parameter that had the wrong type.

This may indicate a bug in PyOTA, but we'll need a bit more context in order to get to the bottom of it, which brings me to:

> (`exc.context["filter_errors"]` contains more information).

Virtually every exception that PyOTA raises has a `context` object attached to it with more information that may be relevant to the error.  Could you modify your code a bit and edit your question to include the output it produces?

```
from pprint import pprint
try:
    bundle = api.get_bundles([tail_hash])['bundles'][0]
except Exception as e:
   pprint(getattr(e, 'context', {}) 
   raise
```

I suspect this will need to be posted on [PyOTA's issue tracker](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.py/issues/), but it would be good to gather more information first.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome. I might be using an old version of the library.
I have updated my question with the requested information

Comment: Solved using a newer version of the library 2.3.0b1. Mea culpa.
Works like a charm. You guys have done a wonderful job. Should I accept your answer or write myself one with the solution?

Comment: Sorry todofixthis

Comment: Sweet as!  I'm glad to hear that you were able to resolve the issue!  Feel free to post your own solution as an answer and accept it — that way other visitors will have two different tools to approach this issue if they encounter it in the future 

Comment: Oh, nevermind; Levente figured it out first 